# Print decimal numbers with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some troubles when creating a cost report, which should contain costs with decimal points. 
Bellow is a list with example costs. When I print the cost to the console (or export to a file), some of the values do not appear as expected.

```py
import decimal
li = [
    {
        "cost": 0E-10
    },
    {
        "cost": 0.0000400000
    },
    {
        "cost": 1.000*0.00005
    },
]

for c in li:
    print(f"Cost: {round(decimal.Decimal(c['cost']), 10)}")

# Cost: 0E-10
# Cost: 0.0000400000
# Cost: 0.0000500000
```

As seen in the output, the first value is displayed as `0E-10` instead of `0`. 
How could I achieve to get all the time decimal numbers printed?

Comment: https://pyformat.info/#number

Comment: As an aside you should not create a variable whose name (`list`) is also the name of a built-in type, function, module, etc. or you could end up with unexpected consequences but at the very least an unreadable program. You probably know this, but this is for others who might be reading this ...